# How do I check a cell is visible in a table view with Xcode 7 UI Testing?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I have a table view with a lot of cells and not every cell is visible on a screen. When I check with

```
table.cells.staticTexts.matchingIdentifier("My Cell").element.exists
```

It returns true but the cell is not visible on the screen and I cannot tap on it. Because whenever I tap on it, a test fails.

How to check if an element is visible on a screen? Or how to tap on an element that is not visible?

Comment: Here is my solution to this problem - hope it helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/33538255/4093106

Answer (score 9):

Use the `hittable` property instead of `exists`.

The [class reference for XCUIElement](http://masilotti.com/xctest-documentation/Classes/XCUIElement.html#//api/name/hittable) explains that the `hittable` property will only return `true` if the element can be touched.

```
table.cells.staticTexts.matchingIdentifier("My Cell").element.hittable
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using element.exists try using element.hittable. This has worked for me, exists returns true if the element is currently in display hierarchy even though it is outside the screen view. hittable returns true only if the element is on screen and its hittable.

Answer (score 0):

The tableview method cellForRowAtIndexPath (**NOT** the delegate method of the same name) will return the cell at some index path if it is currently being displayed, or nil if it is not displayed.

If the user clicks on a button (or if anything happens with any view in your cell), you can also go up the view hierarchy to first find the cell, then the table view, and the method indexPathForCell will give you the index path of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

you can use swipeUp method to scroll down until specific cell will be visible. You can also check that cell exist or not. something like this.

```
XCUIElementQuery *tableQuery = app.tables;
 if (!tablesQuery.cells.staticText[@"some text"].exist){
  [tablesQuery.staticTexts[@"visible cell text"] swipeUp];
}
```