# How can I set the swipe distance when using '-[XCUIElement swipeDown]' in UITest with Xcode7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode-ui-testing

The `XCUIElement.h` class file shows 
`- (void)scrollByDeltaX:(CGFloat)deltaX deltaY:(CGFloat)deltaY;` and 
`- (XCUICoordinate *)coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:(CGVector)normalizedOffset;` functions. But these can't use on iOS device. `XCUIElement.h` provides `- (void)swipeDown` to swipe the tableview. Because of the insufficient distance to swipe down, pull-to-refresh framework just like MJRefresh can't be responded.
So how do I custom the location or use exist function to edit the swipe down distance?

Comment: "Swipe" is not a scroll. It should be used for swipe recognizers, not for scrolling. Therefore you cannot change the distance. Scrolling is one of the old pains of Apples UI Automation but see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33538255/669586

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can drop down to the coordinate APIs to perform a pull-to-refresh.

```
let firstCell = app.staticTexts["Cell One"]
let start = firstCell.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0, 0))
let finish = firstCell.coordinateWithNormalizedOffset(CGVectorMake(0, 6))
start.pressForDuration(0, thenDragToCoordinate: finish)
```

I've put together [more information](http://masilotti.com/ui-testing-cheat-sheet/#how-to-quot-pull-to-refresh-quot) along with a [working sample app](https://github.com/joemasilotti/UI-Testing-Cheat-Sheet) on my blog.

Comment: While this does work, it looks like scrolling its not file tuned. In your answer you have `(CGVectorMake(0, 6)`, but in my app it looks like scrolling just by 1 scroll too much. Is there more to `coordinateWithNormalizedOffset` ? Maybe i just dont know how it works.